# Why is my trait object a mismatched type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return a boxed result of a trait object from a function. My function is returning (seemingly) the correct types to satisfy this trait object. However, the compiler is saying the types are mismatched. Here is my code:

```
use anyhow::Result;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}

trait Wrap {}

struct Wrapper1<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper1<'a> {
    fn new(bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self { bar })
    }
}

impl<'a> Wrap for Wrapper1<'a> {}

struct Wrapper2<'a> {
    bar: &'a Bar,
}

impl<'a> Wrapper2<'a> {
    fn new(bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self { bar })
    }
}

impl<'a> Wrap for Wrapper2<'a> {}

fn wrap<'a>(i: i32, bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Box<dyn Wrap + 'a>> {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        Wrapper1::new(bar).map(Box::new)
    } else {
        Wrapper2::new(bar).map(Box::new)
    }
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:37:9
   |
35 | fn wrap<'a>(i: i32, bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Box<dyn Wrap + 'a>> {
   |                                      -------------------------- expected `Result<Box<(dyn Wrap + 'a)>, anyhow::Error>` because of return type
36 |     if i % 2 == 0 {
37 |         Wrapper1::new(bar).map(Box::new)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<Box<dyn Wrap>, Error>`, found `Result<Box<Wrapper1<'_>>, Error>`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<Box<(dyn Wrap + 'a)>, _>`
              found enum `Result<Box<Wrapper1<'_>>, _>`
help: use `?` to coerce and return an appropriate `Err`, and wrap the resulting value in `Ok` so the expression remains of type `Result`
   |
37 |         Ok(Wrapper1::new(bar).map(Box::new)?)
   |         +++                                ++

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:39:9
   |
35 | fn wrap<'a>(i: i32, bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Box<dyn Wrap + 'a>> {
   |                                      -------------------------- expected `Result<Box<(dyn Wrap + 'a)>, anyhow::Error>` because of return type
...
39 |         Wrapper2::new(bar).map(Box::new)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Result<Box<dyn Wrap>, Error>`, found `Result<Box<Wrapper2<'_>>, Error>`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Result<Box<(dyn Wrap + 'a)>, _>`
              found enum `Result<Box<Wrapper2<'_>>, _>`
help: use `?` to coerce and return an appropriate `Err`, and wrap the resulting value in `Ok` so the expression remains of type `Result`
   |
39 |         Ok(Wrapper2::new(bar).map(Box::new)?)
   |         +++                                ++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `foo` due to 2 previous errors
```

The compiler suggests wrapping my expression like this, which does work.

```
Ok(Wrapper2::new(bar).map(Box::new)?)
+++                                ++
```

However, I don't see why this is necessary, as it seems to leave the types exactly the same. It's also a bit less ergonomic.

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip. I updated the post with the full text of the compiler error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Box::new()` has the signature `fn<T>(T) -> Box<T>`. If it takes `&Bar`, it will return `Box<&Bar>`. Not `Box<dyn Wrap>`, even if you really want it to.

What you actually need is **two** steps: first, wrap the `&Bar` in `Box`, then, coerce it to `Box<dyn Wrap>`. `Box::new()` can and will do the first step willingly, but it just cannot do the second step.

The compiler cannot transform the `Result<Box<&Bar>>` to `Result<Box<dyn Wrap>>` either, because coercion is not transitive: the fact that `Box<&Bar>` can be coerced to `Box<dyn Wrap>` does not mean that `Result<Box<&Bar>>` can coerce to `Result<Box<dyn Wrap>>`.

What the compiler suggests is unwrapping the `Result`: by that, when you extract the `Ok` value, the compiler can coerce the `Box<&Bar>` to `Box<dyn Wrap>`, and then you wrap *that* with `Result`, resulting `Result<Box<dyn Wrap>>`.

Another alternative is to replace `Box::new()` with a custom closure that does the coercion:

```rust
fn wrap<'a>(i: i32, bar: &'a Bar) -> Result<Box<dyn Wrap + 'a>> {
    if i % 2 == 0 {
        Wrapper1::new(bar).map(|v| Box::new(v) as _)
    } else {
        Wrapper2::new(bar).map(|v| Box::new(v) as _)
    }
}
```

`as _` is a hint to the compiler to do a coercion here.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I'm a bit surprised that type coercion is not transitive. Seems like that should be possible.

Comment: @AndyCarlson It cannot be, in the general case: for example, coercing `Box<Box<T>>` to `Box<Box<dyn Trait>>` has to allocate.